# drag drop div in textbox

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I have a repeater in the right side of my page and a textbox at the left of the page. have created the items in repeater in a div so that i can move them into the textbox. on drag drop of the same, the value in the div shall be copied over in the textbox.

Kindly share code if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for something like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/ or http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists?

Grz, Kris.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. since it is a repeater and will contain multiple items, how can i make them draggable ?

Comment: Render <div> elements in every row for example and provide them all with a certain css class on which you can use jQuery to find them $('.draggable').draggable(); for example.